# ISO timestamp is changed to another format in swagger

Tags: r, api, swagger, iso8601, plumber

I am making an R API using the package Plumber. I have created a route where a user will send a company name, start and end timestamp. The route looks like this in my plumber file.

```
#* @param company is the name of the company
#* @param start is a timestamp
#* @param end is a timestamp
#* @get /info_box/<company>/<start>/<end>
function(company,start,end){
  future_result <- future(info_box(company,start,end))
  return(future_result)
}
```

The parameters for start and end time will be passed into a SQL query that is stored in a string variable. This is sent to Athena to be executed. The string looks like this:

```
"SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE completed = true
AND end_time >= CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp('replacement_start') AS TIMESTAMP)
AND end_time <= CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp('replacement_end') AS TIMESTAMP);"
```

replacement_start and replacement_end are replaced with the parameters that the user will send in the API.

In R when I run the API the swagger page appears where I can test the API out with parameters. I enter the following parameters[image]

and I get this result

```
{
  "error": "500 - Internal server error",
  "message": "Error: INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: \"2022-01-01T01%3A00%3A00.000Z\" is malformed at \"%3A00%3A00.000Z\"\n"
}
```

I don't know why swagger is adding %3A00%3A00. I know this is the problem but why is swagger doing this. Is this a different Format than ISO8601 which I am entering?

Comment: It looks like your input is being sanitized / url encoded, so that colons are being replaced with `%3A`. You need to `urldecode` these before passing them to SQL

Comment: Thank you by using the function URLdecode() from utils I was able to pass my parameters as strings to the SQL query in the correct format.